# Sonata Admin restrict action if user type XXX

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I'm using Sonata Admin for a project and i have a problem.

I'm using FosUserBundle and i have several type of users, ex Admin and Superviser.

I have two entities User and Document.

An account type Admin can manage Document and User, but I want a Superviser can only manage Document.

How can I do that ?

When I connect with a Superviser, I don't want to have the choice to create edit etc... a user

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

[Sonata Admin Docs - Security](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/2-3/doc/reference/security.html)

Looks like your situation can be handled with [Roles](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/2-3/doc/reference/security.html#role-handler):

**Incorporate FOSUserBundle into Sonata Admin with SonataUserBundle** (you may already have done this)

**Set up appropriate roles in `security.yml`.**  These are standard Symfony Roles, but following a special Sonata Admin naming convention, e.g. (adapted from docs with your Entities):

*app/config/security.yml*

```
security:
    ...
    role_hierarchy:
        #collect specific Sonata permissions together for convenience
        ROLE_SONATA_USER:
            - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_DEMO_USER_LIST
            - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_DEMO_USER_VIEW
            - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_DEMO_USER_CREATE
            - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_DEMO_USER_EDIT
            - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_DEMO_USER_DELETE
        ROLE_SONATA_DOCUMENT:
            - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_DEMO_DOCUMENT_LIST
            - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_DEMO_DOCUMENT_VIEW
            - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_DEMO_DOCUMENT_CREATE
            - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_DEMO_DOCUMENT_EDIT
            - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_DEMO_DOCUMENT_DELETE
        #roles actually assigned to users
        ROLE_SUPERVISER:             [ROLE_USER, ROLE_SONATA_DOCUMENT]
        ROLE_ADMIN:             [ROLE_USER, ROLE_SONATA_DOCUMENT, ROLE_SONATA_USER]
```

**Assign ROLE_SUPERVISER and ROLE_ADMIN to users** (via FOSUserBundle commands or $user->addRole)

These are then used by Sonata to limit access to functions, and e.g. to show which panels are appropriate on the main dashboard, and you yourself can test them to customised your own views etc